# HEVC/H265 videos not playing in SM Player

Tags: video, vlc, hevc

I use SM Player for all videos.
Whenever i try to play HEVC/H265 videos sm player doesn't play it.

There is no h265 listed in codec list.
screen-shot:- http://prntscr.com/92x1is

I use Gnome Ubuntu 15.10
64-bit
I have latest version of SM Player.

H265/HEVC videos plays smoothly in vlc and default video player in ubuntu but it only not works in SM Player.
While in windows OS it plays smooth in SM Player but same file doesn't play in Ubuntu.
HEVC codec are already installed in ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SMPlayer by default uses mplayer executable as its backend. You would need it to use mpv player instead.

Install mpv player first.

```
sudo apt-get install mpv
```

Then open SMPlayer and go to its options. Change the location in Mplayer/mpv executable to

```
/usr/bin/mpv
```

That should fix it. Make sure you have SMPlayer 15.9 installed.

Comment: getting the following error after trying to use mpv via SMplayer with the above solution:

Driver 'gl' has been replaced with 'opengl'!
Error parsing option yuv (option not found)
Option vo: Error while parsing gl parameter yuv (2)
Error parsing option vo (option could not be parsed)
Setting command line option '--vo=gl:yuv=2:force-pbo' failed.
Exiting... (Fatal error)

ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: BUMP CAN WE FIGURE THIS OUT YET>

Comment: Don't works. [On Mint Mate 17.2]